# How to create a custom block using the RESTfull API

Tags: 8

I have to create a block by calling a custom Rest based services but didn't find anything specific to that as of now in drupal8. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: How are you planning on rendering it on the page? Are you creating a custom block plugin?

Comment: Thanks @Matt for your reply. I have found the solution as it is already there in core by using Restful API modules to get and create blocks and it works better for me.